# Generating raster from pixel values using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have been given a table which is a series of pixel location & values. For example:

```
   1  2  3
1  1  2  3
2  3  ?  2
3  2  2  1
```

Obviously the real table is large and also have missing values just like in example.

Pixel row and column number start from top left. Also pixel size is know.

How do I convert it to raster for visualization and analysis purpose using ArcMap 10.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of thinking and consulting with few colleagues, we reached a very rough work around. Steps:

1) Pivot table so we end up with columns: pixel value, x, y.

2) Import to gis using x,y data as point feature class.

3) Use spatial adjustment to georeference point data.

4) Generate a fishnet.

5) Spatial Join to get attribute (pixel value) to fishnet.

6) Convert to raster if required.

7) Request source to never send data in this format.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been helpful to potential answerers if you had uploaded a sample file. The table/file you got might be in ASCII format. You may want to have a look at [ASCII to Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000002s000000) tool in ArcMap. If you got a simple text file then probably converting it into asc format would be less of a hassle than your current approach.